# how to get equi-height rows using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my code

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in descArray | filter : searchTxt">
    <div class="col-md-6">{{obj.description}}</div>
</div>
```

I wanted it to be either 3 column layout (col-md-4) or two column layout (col-md-6) based on page design. The problem here is that I wanted my rows to be of equal height with a border for each div.

I cannot fix the height of the div as it may be dynamic hence I want divs in a single row to be aligned properly with equal height in a single row.

I tried various ways such as clearfix method in this case each div is aligned within its row but my div's borders are not of same height.

```
<div ng-repeat-start="obj in descArray | filter : searchTxt">      
      <div class="col-md-6">{{obj.description}}</div>
      <div class="clearfix " ng-if="$index%2===1"></div>
<div ng-repeat-end=""></div>
```

Also wanted to support ng-repeat filter.